# Alternative to disable-output-escaping for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

I'm using a Content Query Web Part and ItemStyle.xsl to pull in content from a rich text field.  Unfortunately, it escapes the code so it doesn't render HTML tags.  Disable-output-escaping doesn't work in FF (weird) so I can't use it. Any alternatives?  Does SP have a different way to unescape the characters?

Comment: Please, provide a source XML document, a transformation, the result produced and the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

From http://allthingssharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/output-escaping-rich-text-in-a-content-query-web-part/

To fix this, you need to edit the ItemStyle.xsl (preferably a custom one, see [this post](http://allthingssharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/code-easy-modifications-for-sharepoint-2010-part-2-the-custom-content-query-web-part-item-style/)). You would just have to add the following command to the part outputting the HTML:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$blah"/>
```

Comment: Without code snippets, it's tough to tell what you've done. On re-reading your question, it sounds like this might be what you tried.

Comment: Yea I know that, but it doesn't work in Firefox.  I'm looking to see if there's an alternative that works in both.  Or if I can do it in the web part directly so it's server side.

Answer (score 0):

Disable-output-escaping sends instructions to the serializer; it therefore has no effect when you are not serializating. In Firefox the result tree produced by the XSLT processor is rendered directly without being serialized and re-parsed, therefore d-o-e has no effect.

The workaround is usually to write the XSLT code properly in the first place. 90% of the time when people use d-o-e they are doing so because they haven't learned to use XSLT the way it was designed to be used. So show us your problem, and we can suggest how to solve it without d-o-e.

Comment: Well it's a rich-text editor field in SharePoint that's returning the XML, so I don't really know if I can even change it.  And since it's a rich text editor, it stores in all HTML tags too.

Comment: @zen: If you are unable to give us a specific example, then you don't really have a problem at all. Why are you wasting yours and everybody's time? Please, edit the question and provide a specific XML document, the desired result and any rules for the transformation -- these make a real question.